# Mapping DynamoDB table to CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to set up a CloudSearch domain that is searching my dynamoDB table. I have looked at the example for the IMDB and it looks nothing like they way I have it.

I have followed a lot of tutorials and it still seems messed up.

How to I map my table loosly to the indexed fields and have them return correctly.

Here is my DynamoDB Structure

```
{
  "account": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "phone": "0123 456 789"
  },
  "address": [
    {
        "id": "28723",
        "unit": "12",
        "floor": "4",
        "street_number": "546",
        "street_name": "Smith St",
        "suburb": "Melbourne",
        "postcode": "2000",
        "country": "Australia"
    }
  ],
  "agreedToTermsAndConditions": true,
  "billing": {
    "reference": "123456789"
  },
  "dates": {
    "created": "2018-02-27T05:20:57.810Z"
  },
  "email": "johnsmith@gmail.com",
  "id": "354684354-4b32-53e3-8949846-211384",
  "orders": {},
  "password": "XXX",
  "site_id": "1"
}
```

How do I set the CloudSearch Indexing Options to a DynamoDB table with the structure like this, so that I can search for any of the items in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really the solution. However I found that using AWS elastic search and running the instance through that was easier to set up than CloudSearch.